# How to override dependency version of a nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, assembly-loading

I have a .netstandard2.0 project, let's say it is called common, which is using **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager** 5.0.0 and **log4net** 2.0.15 from nuget.org.
This common project is used by project A which is a .net5 project, and also used by project B, which is a .net framework 4.6.1 project.
In Common project, I use **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager** and **log4net** like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.15" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now I got assembly loading issue of **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll** when **log4net** tries to initialize, because it needs 4.0.1.0 of **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager** instead of 5.0.0.

The error message looks like this:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I force log4net.dll to use **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager** 5.0.0.0?
I tried to add a log4net.dll.config as below, but not working. **log4net** still tries to load the older version of **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager**. Anyone knows how to solve this issue except rebuild **log4net** from source?

```xml
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I checked metadata of log4net.dll, it does use 4.0.1.0 version **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager**. I tried to rebinding with above syntax, but seems being ignored.

To reproduce this issue, you need to set output folder of A and B are the same:

```xml
<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)$(Configuraiton)$(Platform)</OutputPath>
<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
```

Also, I found that If I rebuild A only (or rebuild solution, three projects A, B and Common are in the same solution), then check **log4net.dll** properties in the output folder by right click -> Properties -> Details, the Product version shows "2.0.15.0-NET Standard 2.0". However, If I rebuild B only, it becomes "2.0.15.0-.NET 4.5", in this case the issue is gone. The assembly loading issue only happens when log4net.dll shows "2.0.15.0-NET Standard 2.0".

Comment: According to Nuget, log4net 2.0.15 works with System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager v4.5.0 or higher. Could it be some other dependent package that requires v4.0.1 specifically? Not sure that really fixes the problem but it would be good to know exactly what dependency is the issue.

Comment: What's the target framework? Also, you typically never hand roll assembly binding redirects. There is a problem with the one there: the publicKeyToken is not correct. It should be `cc7b13ffcd2ddd51`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney target framework version of log4net 2.0.15 is .netstandard2.0. This assembly is referenced in a .netstandard2.0 common assembly, which is used by both .net 5 project and .net framework 4.6.1 project.

Comment: @Hank I double checked my configuration, the publicKeyToken is the same as yours. The one in the post I copied from somewhere, it's not correct. I have fixed it.

Comment: I appreciate the edits to provide more context. It seems there may be more going on because I cannot repro this with the code I created given your new description. Join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252571/room-for-hymccord-and-ben-yu and I can help you out further.

Comment: Thanks @Hank. Yes, the actual code and environment is much more complicated than I have described here. Project A or B are actually loaded via reflection. There are many other projects depends on **Common** project, and A or B depends on them as well, they are just final assemblies for running.  They are started dynamically via reflection in a distributed computing environment. Not sure if it's caused by the reflection with incorrect assembly loading order.

Comment: @Hank I have added more information regarding how to reproduce this issue, and I also found that If I add binding redirect to project B, it seems working. Unfortunately, it's not working in actual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is finally coming together with the latest information you provided.

The fundamental problem is building two separate '.NET' implementations into the same folder. There's a reason `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` exists.

A `.NET` dll cannot rely on a `.NETFramework` class library and vice-versa is also true. And that essentially what is happening here. The outputs of the build are clobbering each other and what runs is basically the one you built most recently.

When I set up my projects the way you describe I can recreate it.
ProjectA: `net5.0`, ProjectB: `net461`, Common: `netstandard2.0`.

Build `A` -> Build `B`. `B` runs fine but `A` does not.
Build `B` -> Build `A`. `A` runs fine but `B` does not.

If I add this hand rolled assembly binding redirect to `B`'s appconfig

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Build `B` -> Build `A`. Both work, but this is **very** unreliable.

If the assemblies are started via reflection, then you need to be extra careful because you need to make sure the CLR is loading the config files in the same way as it naturally would when starting the EXEs. This is what sets up all the binding redirects (app.config for `.NETFramework`, `deps.json` for `.NET`).

Comment: Thank you very much @Hank. I have a question here, shouldn't be .netstandard compatible with both .net(core) and .net framework? I make the **Common** project .netstandard, it should be working for both .net(core) and .net framework projects. Isn't the purpose of the .netstandard? I can understand that .net framework project can't be used as a dependency of a .net (core) project. Also [log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/#versions-body-tab) says it supports both.

Comment: .netstandard is not a platform... it is a standard. It is a common API set that other platforms must implement to be compliant. You can think of netstandard like an `interface` and the classes are implemented in either `.NETFrameork` or `.NET`.  It will work for both projects but not when you build to the same folder and that's because the build system puts specific dlls out there depending on what final platform you are building for.

Comment: You are also running into this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1791#issuecomment-540985034 because log4net provides a net45 implementation which gets preferred over the netstandard when you build your net46 project.

Comment: @benyu I think you should give Hank some credit here for his answer. Cheers!